# How to click a button with an extension in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, document

So I am using an extension which should open a page and click a button.
So it just opens the page but doesn't click the button. What am I doing wrong? The ID of the button is right. I tried to put it in the console and it clicked the button.

```
// Import On/Off Toggle
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("onofftoggle").onclick =
        function onoff() {
            // Get the checkbox
            var checkBox = document.getElementById("onofftoggle");

            // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
            if (checkBox.checked == true) {
                text.style.display = "block";

                // Run the main script
                //Get Wikipediabutton with ID "run"
                document.getElementById('run').addEventListener('click', onclick, false)


                // Call open window function
                function sleep(milliseconds) {
                return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
                }
                async function onclick() {
                    window.open('https://www.mediamarkt.de/de/product/_trust-gxt-323-carus-2724281.html');
                    await sleep(5000);
                    var hangoutButton = document.getElementById("pdp-add-to-cart-button");
                    hangoutButton.click(); // this will trigger the click event
                }
            } else {
                text.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: `document` in `document.getElementById("pdp-add-to-cart-button");` is the current window's document, not the window you opened. Set a variable to the output of `window.open` and use `win.document.getElementById(...)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript get element from opened window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291770/javascript-get-element-from-opened-window)

Comment: Note that you may have issues with getting the button in the newly opened window, depending on the extension's capabilities.

Comment: Hey @YvesKlaus - following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below any answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. ***Otherwise, please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question.*** If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). Remember, too: you can upvote any answers you found helpful (you can also upvote and checkmark the same answer, if desired.) *Thanks!*

Comment: @YvesKlaus This question is still open. Please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside an answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). That would help us out. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using an extension like TamperMonkey (you should specify which extension for more finely-tuned assistance).

But if you are using an extension like TamperMonkey, sometimes you need to stick your code inside a setTimeout(), because the DOM just isn't quite ready at the moment the injected javascript is fired.

Over the years I've tried using various methods in my scripts like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {})
```

and checking the `document.readyState`

-- and often those work --

But sometimes wrapping your code inside a setTimeout, as inelegant as that is, remains the best solution. My own approach is to start with a ridiculous timeout (say 10 seconds) and adjust down ( /2 ) until it fails.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //your code here
},10000); //10sec timeout before your code runs
```

---

### Update:

However, looking again at your code, I see that you are trying to press the button after opening another window. **Note that you will need to write a separate script** and attach it to that new window *(in TamperMonkey, via the `//match` line)* because once that new window is opened your script, running on the first window, cannot see the button in the second window.

Comment: The OP is already using a `sleep` function of 5 seconds between `window.open` and `document.getElementById`. They're just using the wrong `document`. A common mistake I'm sure we have plenty of duplicates for...